# Cannot bring up "Reference Chooser" window from Properties in Eclipse Android SDK

Tags: android

Using this tutorial at this section 4.5 : 
http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#first_uiproperties as a
guide, I attempt to "Select the complete widget and use the Properties view to
set the property "background" to the color attribute "myColor"."

I can select the widget, highlight the 'Background' property, and when i press
the [...] button in the value column the Reference Chooser Window never appears
and the Value [...] button disapears.

Reproducible: Always

Steps to Reproduce:
1.Highlight the Widget in the Layout View
2.Highlight the Background Property
3.Press [...] button under Value

Comment: I found a work around.  If I mouse right click on the "..." button, and then I press space bar, the reference chooser pops up.  Pain, but a work around nontheless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a work around. If I mouse right click on the "..." button, and then I press space bar, the reference chooser pops up. Pain, but a work around nontheless.